# Azure Web API, number of threads growing under load, most of them awaiting SqlConnection.Close to complete

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-4.5, sqlclient

We're running a Web API app in Azure. Sometimes under load app starts increasing number of working threads.

We can't reproduce the problem in environment other than production and only when it happens (still looking for a reason).

Using [Azure DaaS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/daas/), we were able to get process dumps of w3wp in these situations and most of the threads are waiting on `SqlConnection.Close` to complete.

[image: memory dump from w3wp.exe opened in VS 2017]

Precisely, all these threads are stuck at [this line](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/27f42738d096a95419acbbf00f84c705536f795a/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs#L1438) in  `SqlInternalConnectionTds.ObtainAdditionalLocksForClose`. On different occasions, we have from 300 to 1000+ threads like this.

**Wondering**, what could lead to the situation when `SqlConnection.Close` is locked or stuck or takes long time?

Complete call stack of these threads below or [as a gist](https://gist.github.com/alexsorokoletov/aabdbe007029e730b78ae49a1efc77b0):

```
[Managed to Native Transition]  
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.WaitUntilCountOrTimeout(int millisecondsTimeout, uint startTime, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.Wait(int millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.Wait()  Unknown
System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.SyncAsyncLock.Wait(bool canReleaseFromAnyThread) Unknown
System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ObtainAdditionalLocksForClose()  Unknown
System.Data.dll!System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.CloseConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningObject, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) Unknown
System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Close() Unknown
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.IDbConnectionInterceptor>.Dispatch<System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionInterceptionContext>(System.Data.Common.DbConnection target, System.Action<System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionInterceptionContext> operation, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionInterceptionContext interceptionContext, System.Action<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.IDbConnectionInterceptor, System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionInterceptionContext> executing, System.Action<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.IDbConnectionInterceptor, System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionInterceptionContext> executed) Unknown
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Close(System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)   Unknown
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.StoreCloseHelper()    Unknown
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ReleaseConnection()   Unknown
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper<*.WebApi.Models.Database.T_Table>.Finally()  Unknown
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper<System.__Canon>.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.Dispose()    Unknown
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsyncEnumerator<System.__Canon>.Dispose()   Unknown
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync<*.WebApi.Models.Database.T_Table>(System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerable<*.WebApi.Models.Database.T_Table> source, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()    Unknown
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter<bool>.UnsafeOnCompleted.AnonymousMethod__0() Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action action, bool allowInlining, ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTask)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>.TrySetResult(bool result)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<bool>.SetResult(bool result)    Unknown
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsyncEnumerator<*.WebApi.Models.Database.T_Table>.FirstMoveNextAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()    Unknown
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter<System.__Canon>.UnsafeOnCompleted.AnonymousMethod__0()   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action action, bool allowInlining, ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTask)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon>.TrySetResult(System.__Canon result)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<*.WebApi.Models.Database.T_Table>>.SetResult(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<*.WebApi.Models.Database.T_Table> result)    Unknown
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<*.WebApi.Models.Database.T_Table>.GetResultsAsync(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.MergeOption? forMergeOption, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()    Unknown
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter<System.__Canon>.UnsafeOnCompleted.AnonymousMethod__0()   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action action, bool allowInlining, ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTask)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon>.TrySetResult(System.__Canon result)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<*.WebApi.Models.Database.T_Table>>.SetResult(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<*.WebApi.Models.Database.T_Table> result)    Unknown
EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll!System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsyncImplementation<System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<*.WebApi.Models.Database.T_Table>>(System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<*.WebApi.Models.Database.T_Table>>> func)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action action, bool allowInlining, ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTask)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon>.TrySetResult(System.__Canon result)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<*.WebApi.Models.Database.T_Table>>.SetResult(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<*.WebApi.Models.Database.T_Table> result)    Unknown
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransactionAsync<System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<*.WebApi.Models.Database.T_Table>>(System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<*.WebApi.Models.Database.T_Table>>> func, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, bool startLocalTransaction, bool releaseConnectionOnSuccess, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()    Unknown
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter<System.__Canon>.UnsafeOnCompleted.AnonymousMethod__0()   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action action, bool allowInlining, ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTask)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon>.TrySetResult(System.__Canon result)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<*.WebApi.Models.Database.T_Table>>.SetResult(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<*.WebApi.Models.Database.T_Table> result)    Unknown
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.ExecuteAsync<*.WebApi.Models.Database.T_Table>(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext context, System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()    Unknown
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter<System.__Canon>.UnsafeOnCompleted.AnonymousMethod__0()   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action action, bool allowInlining, ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTask)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon>.TrySetResult(System.__Canon result)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader>.SetResult(System.Data.Common.DbDataReader result)  Unknown
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommandsAsync(System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityCommand entityCommand, System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()    Unknown
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter<System.__Canon>.UnsafeOnCompleted.AnonymousMethod__0()   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action action, bool allowInlining, ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTask)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(bool bUserDelegateExecuted) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.TryRunInline(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuation.InlineIfPossibleOrElseQueue(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, bool needsProtection)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon>.TrySetResult(System.__Canon result)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader>.TrySetFromTask(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, bool lookForOce)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise<System.__Canon>.ProcessInnerTask(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise<System.__Canon>.Invoke(System.Threading.Tasks.Task completingTask)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(bool bUserDelegateExecuted) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    Unknown
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

P.S.: Link to the source code file leads to SqlClient for .NET Core, though it looks like .NET 4.5.2 (we're using) is having exactly same or similar implementation. At least all method names and classes are the same in the call stack.